# Depends on vs depend on

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, singular-vs-plural, grammaticality-in-context

The type of music peter listens ***depends*** on his mood

or

The type of music peter listens ***depend*** on his mood.

My question is which one is correct? And which word determines it: music, Peter or listens?

Answer (score 1):

You have added the tag 'singular-vs-plural' to your question, but this is nothing at all to do with plurals. 'Depend' is a **verb**, and this is about verb forms and tense. You may have been taught that suffixing an 's' makes some *nouns* plural, but don't confuse that with all words that end in 's'.

Verbs with a third-person singular noun or pronoun (he, she, it) as a subject have an added s on the end, for example:

- I depend (first person)
- He depends
- It depends

This is the same for many verbs:

- I swim / he swims
- I live / it lives

In fact, you should know this because you've used the verb 'listen'. "Peter listens" is correct, but it would be "I listen".

---

The correct form for use in your sentence is '*depends*':

> The type of music peter listens to *depends* on his mood.

This is because 'the type of music' is the thing which depends on something else, and it (the type of music) is a third-person-singular.

You could also say:

> Peter listens to different types of music *depending* on his mood.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: It should be, "The type of music Peter listens to ...", not "The type of music Peter listens ...". Or if you want to follow the pedantic rule that a preposition must always be followed by its object, you could say, "The type of music to which Peter listens ..."

But to get to your question: In some languages, there is an extensive set of endings attached to verbs depending on tense and person. In English this is very sparse. In the present tense, we generally add an "s" to a verb if the subject is third person singular. That is, "I depend", "you depend", "he **depends**", "we depend", "you depend", "they depend". The verb form is the same for all except the third person singular.

So the question here is, what is the subject of "depend/s"? It's "The type". "The type ... depends on ..." "Type" is third person singular. So the verb should be "depends", not "depend".

Which to pick does not depend on "Peter" or "listens" as neither of these is the subject of the verb "depends".